# Adding a jabber client as portlet in NetSuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, converse.js

Is it possible to add an open source jabber client such as converse.js via portlet or suitelet's online html field and attaching that somehow to a record ?

I tried by adding the converse.min.js as a library script file and converse.min.css in the file cabinet , but couldn't get it to work.

If someone has worked with such a scenario , I'd really appreciate the insights and advice.

Comment: Can you give some more details on "couldn't get it to work"? Attaching a library file is the correct approach, depending on what exactly you're trying to do. I've never worked with converse.js specifically, but we pull in libraries like jquery UI, lodash.js and moment.js all the time to use, so it should be perfectly possible to pull in converse.js

Comment: I'm getting a suitescript error , cannot read property "defaultView" from undefined (converse.min#237) when I attached converse.min.js in the Html <head> </head> tags.

Comment: Can you please add code samples of how you are referencing `defaultView` and also how you are including converse.min.js in your HTML? This will help with troubleshooting.

Comment: Inside my get code I am adding this :var html = '<html><head>';
html += '<link href="' + nlapiEscapeXML("https://system.na1.netsuite.com/core/media/media.nl?id=#&c=#&h=###&mv=ihdbx954&_xt=.css") + '" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">' ; // Link to file I uploaded in the file cabinet
    html += '<script src= \"converse.min.js\"> ' ; // Attached as lib script
    html += '</script>' ;     &  the defaultView is the part of the converse.min.js itself which I downloaded from https://github.com/jcbrand/converse.js.   Sorry i know I'm a n00b :) Thanks for the help.

Comment: @egrubaugh360  -- Hi, Sorry I couldn't give much info on how defaultView was being referenced as it was present in the minified file & I had no idea how to make sense of it.   Anyways, one of my friend suggested to make the library files being sourced-- "Available without login" & upon doing that the script is working as desired.  Thanks for your help though & apologies for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing the library scripts file records I was attaching with my Suitelet script and enabling "Available Without login" checkbox for each one of them solved the issue for me.